Checking odds and evens
I do not understand this question.
I create a function or callable object that takes an integer as an argument and returns "Even" for even numbers or "Odd" for odd numbers. The function should also return "Even" or "Odd" when accessing a value at an integer index. This part is somewhat confusing because we are not accessing an array or passing an array through the function. My function is as follows:
function evenOrOdd(n) {
  //'Even' or 'Odd'
  if(n==0){
    return 'Even';
  }else if(n%2==0){
    return 'Even';
  }
  else{
    return 'Odd';
  }
}

But then tests are like this:
const chai = require('chai');
const assert = chai.assert;

describe("Sample tests",() => {
  
  it("[4] is even", () => {
    assert.strictEqual(evenOrOdd[4], "Even"); //<--- How do I solv this? Test Fails
  });
  it("2 is even", () => {
    assert.strictEqual(evenOrOdd(2), "Even"); //<--- Test Passd as expected
  });
  it("[11] is odd", () => {
    assert.strictEqual(evenOrOdd[11], "Odd"); //<--- How do I solv this? Test Fails
  });
  it("7 is odd", () => {
    assert.strictEqual(evenOrOdd(7), "Odd"); // Test Passd as expected
  });
  
});

What am I not understanding here and how do I overcome this?

evenOrOdd is a function ... why do you use it in different (alternating) ways in your code? i.e. as a function evenOrOdd(2) and evenOrOdd(7) AND also try to access its [4] and [11] properties as if it were not a function

@JaromandaX is correct - change your lines to evenOrOdd(4) and evenOrOdd(11) -- note the brackets!

I fully understand that it is a function, but the requirement is to have "The function should also return "Even" or "Odd" when accessing a value at an integer index." That is part of the requirement. It just doesn't seem possible and/or counter intuitive.

Are those tests something you were provided with that you need to solve for or have you written them yourself with perhaps a misunderstanding of the requirements?

The title of the question can be better. If you know what you want, just be straightforward and ask it well.

@Phil Those are the test cases that were provided to me

You can't call a function with square brackets; if you want to do that (I'm not sure why, but I'm sure this question is for some bigger picture), then you need to create a Proxy object to act as a proxy to your evenOrOdd function.
Something along the lines of this:


function evenOrOdd(n) {
  if (n % 2 === 0) {
    return 'Even';
  } else {
    return 'Odd';
  }
}

const evenOrOddProxy = new Proxy(evenOrOdd, {
  get: function(target, prop) {
    if (!isNaN(prop)) {
      return evenOrOdd(Number(prop));
    }
    return target[prop];
  }
});

// Tests
console.log('Tests:')
console.log(evenOrOddProxy[4] === "Even")  // <-- true
console.log(evenOrOddProxy(2) === "Even")  // <-- true
console.log(evenOrOddProxy[11] === "Odd")  // <-- true
console.log(evenOrOddProxy(7) === "Odd")   // <-- true




Wrap the function in a Proxy object
Use a get trap in the Proxy to intercept property accesses. When a numeric property (e.g., 4 or 11) is accessed, it calls the evenOrOdd function with that number.

This allows both function calls with parentheses and property accesses with square brackets.

That proxy really helped. I didn't even know that it was possible to do that. I have tried to google it but no result was found. WHich it was irritating
